# Regular Expression to match only letters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need write a regular expression for RegularExpressionValidator ASP.NET Web Controls.

The regular expression should ALLOW all alphabetic characters but not numbers or special characters (example: |!"£$%&/().

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

validates a string of length 1 or greater, consisting only of ASCII letters.

```
^[^\W\d_]+$
```

does the same for international letters, too.

Explanation:

```
[^   # match any character that is NOT a
\W   # non-alphanumeric character (letters, digits, underscore)
\d   # digit
_    # or underscore
]    # end of character class
```

Effectively, you get `\w` minus (`\d` and `_`).

Or, you could use the fact that ASP.NET supports Unicode properties:

```
^\p{L}+$
```

validates a string of Unicode letters of length 1 or more.

Comment: Great answer; to complement it: `\p{Ll}` only matches lowercase characters, and `\p{Lu}` only uppercase ones.

Comment: @FrankHintsch: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) :)

Answer (score 8):

Including spaces:

```
"^[a-zA-Z ]*$"
```

Excluding Spaces:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]*$"
```

To make it non-optional, change the `*` to a `+`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Explanation:

- `^` : Start anchor
- `[..]` : Char class
- `+` : one or more repetations
- `$` : End anchor